# Sync problem related to viso2

Tags: ros, syncronization, gscam, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All.
I'm trying to setup and run Viso2 node in ros fuerte. I have a problem related to a sync warning in gscam, so I asked this question:*http://answers.ros.org/question/84611/synchronized-problem-related-to-calibration/*

When I updated the code version of GSCAM, I could see the rectify image when I used the image_view node.

But my problem now is when I tried  to Subscribed that topic (Image_rect) to Viso2 node, It show again the sync msg (warning message), this following  message:

[WARN] [1381282007.181977693]: [
image_transport] Topics '/Dava/image_rect_color' and '/Dava/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:

```
Image messages received:      100

CameraInfo messages received: 0

Synchronized pairs:           0
```

And when I used the command "rostop echo /mono_odometer/info" I don't see anything.

So I don't know if the problem is with my viso2 configuration or is a problem with GSCAM.

I attached the output, my camera calibration info (From rostopic echo) and rxgraph output.
And you can download my lauch file in this link (): *https://mega.co.nz/#!W9pkkD5Q!NcRUbm0drgoKXXoli6rHDGUKEHBebpktfsO4Wd2tDas*

I will appreciate any respond . Thank

[output.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13812828878070684.png)

[rostopic echo camera info.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13812829034102762.png)

[Rxgraph.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13812829171176873.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88926/sync-problem-related-to-viso2./) by [Dava2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/3554/dava2788/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make sure your remappings are setup right. From your rxgraph output it looks like the mono_odometer is only subscribed to the image_rect topic and not to the camera_info topic.

Using `rosnode info mono_odometer` you can have a quick look at the topic connections.

`image_proc` is designed to run in the camera's namespace:

```
<node pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" name="image_proc" ns="/Dava/camera" />
```

This way you have all camera-related topics together:

```
  /Dava/camera/image_raw
  /Dava/camera/camera_info
  /Dava/camera/image_rect
  /Dava/camera/image_mono
  ...
```

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1